# To be XML serializable, types which inherit from ICollection must have an implementation of Add

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, oop, csla

I have CSLA (1.x framework) objects from an existing project that I'm trying to use in a new .Net 4.0 project.  The objects are being used in production and I really can't convert them to 2.x or EF without having 2 sets of objects.

In my c# webservice (when I try to run it) I am getting the following error:

> ```
> To be XML serializable, types which inherit from ICollection must
> have an implementation of Add(objectname.object) at all levels
> of their inheritance hierarchy. objectname.objectList does not
> implement Add(objectname.object).
> ```

Like I said these objects are CSLA objects written in vb.net.  I don't know where to look on this one.  Is it an issue of .Net 4.0 trying to talk to CSLA 1.x or is it a web service issue (as these objects never used web services originally)?

Does anyone have an idea about where I should look to figure out this issue?  Should I suggest converting to CSLA 2.x?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an XmlSerializer limitation; if something looks like a list of data, it will want to Add items to it via the Add method.

If you have access to those objects, consider adding such a method. I can't recall whether it wants Add(object) vs Add(SomeType) so try both.

If you *don't* have control over those objects... it will be hard. It would be quicker to write a new DTO layer for the objects than to try to patch it somehow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...  What does DTO stand for?  I do have control over those objects however, they are also being used in another project which would mean I would have to include more people in this type of change.  So your DTO option is intriguing...

Comment: @Jeff - Data Transfer Object - i.e. a set of classes *specifically* for the purposes of serialization

Comment: @Jeff - but in this case it sounds like you should be able to just add the missing `Add`?